# What characters does $# count?

Tags: bash, count

I'm having trouble determining what characters '$#' actually counts

Example:

```sh
bold=$'\e[1m'
red=$'\e[0;31m'
clr=$'\e[0m'

string="${red}[!]${clr} ${bold}Warning:${clr} foo bar"

printf "String count: %s\n" "${#string}"
```

Output:

```
String count: 39
```

The length of `string` with its variables is 45 characters. The length of `string` with its variables substituted is 43 characters (i.e. `\e[0;31m` in place of `${red}`, etc.).

So, what characters is the shell not counting for it to output 39 as the total length of the string?

Comment: I counted 39 character. How did you count 45 characters? `$'\e'` is one character, not two.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks. That's essentially what I was after. I wasn't sure if $# counted escaped characters as one or two characters, or if it counted them at all

Answer (score -1):

To simplify the answer, consider the strings `'\n'`, and `$'\n'`

This first is 2 characters. The second is single character (newline).

As per bash man:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands
>   to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced  as  specified by
>   the ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:
>
> ```
>           ...
>           \n     new line
>           \r     carriage return
>           \t     horizontal tab
>           ...
> ```

Replacement of backslash-escaped characters also occur with `echo -e`, evaluation of various dynamic parameters (TIMEFORMAT, PS2, ..). Many utilities will parse escape sequences (e.g., `sed`, `tr`), sometimes with different rules. Unfortunately, those situation, in many cases dictated by backward compatibility can be confusing and may conflict with each other, sometimes resulting in having to double, triple and sometimes quadruple escapes, when strings have to be passed to external programs.